# Getting Last rows from the result of Linq to Sql statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I couldn't get last articles of every writers in this statement.

```
List<Editor> lstEditors = dataContext.GetTable<Editor>().Where(t => t.M_Active).Select(t => t).ToList();

var lstArticles = from article in DAO.context.GetTable<Article>().ToList()
join editor in lstEditors on article.RefEditorId equals editor.EditorId 
select
    new
    {
        article.M_ArticleId,
        article.M_Subject,
        article.M_Text,
        editor.M_EditorId,
        editor.M_Member.M_EditorPicture,
        M_NameSurname = editor.M_Member.M_Fname + " " + editor.M_Member.M_Lname
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful, your query is fetching **all the contents** of both the **Editor** and the **Yazi** tables and then performs Linq-to-Objects on it.

I'm not sure what you ask exactly either, do you want to obtain the list of all writers (editors) along with the last article of each one of these writers?

Do you want to get the writers that did not write any articles yet also?

**Edit:**

*explanation of methods causing an immediate query*

Any time you call one of the methods listed below on an IQueryable object (tables or other queries), it performs the actual query to SQL server:

- ToList(), ToArray(), ToLookup(), ToDictionay()
- Count(), Sum(), Avg(), Aggregate(), Min(), Max()
- First(), FirstOrDefault(), Last(), LastOrDefault()

*getting last article written by each writer*

```
//create a subquery that returns an editor and its last article date
var editorLastArticleDates =
    from article in DAO.context.GetTable<Article>()
    group article by article.RefEditor into g
    let lastArticleDate= g.Max(x => x.Date)
    select new
    {
        Editor = g.Key,
        LastArticleDate = lastArticleDate,
    };
//Note: We did not do a ToList() here so the query is not executed
//      The editorLastArticleDates object is a IQueryable<>

var query =
    from article in DAO.context.GetTable<Article>()
    join editorLastArticleDate in editorLastArticleDates 
        on new { article.Editor, article.Date }                     // 1
        equals new { editorLastArticleDate.Editor,                  // 2
                     Date = editorLastArticleDate.LastArticleDate } // 3
    select new
    {
        article.M_ArticleId,
        article.M_Subject,
        article.M_Text,
        article.RefEditor.M_EditorId,
        article.RefEditor.M_Member.M_EditorPicture,
        M_NameSurname = article.RefEditor.M_Member.M_Fname + " "
                      + article.RefEditor.M_Member.M_Lname,
    };
//Note: We did not do a ToList() yet so the query is not executed
//      The query object is a IQueryable<>

Console.WriteLine(query.ToString()); //Displays SQL query on the console

var results = query.ToList(); // SQL query is executed on this line.
```

In the code above, I left some remarks on things I had problems with:

1. When using join, the section between `new` and `equals` access only variables declared *before* the `join` keyword while the section after the `equals` keyword has access to the variable defined between `join` and `in`.
2. When writing your join condition, make sure you use `equals` and not `==`.
3. When using `new { XXX, YYY }` syntax in your join condition, you declare anonymous types. If the property names are not identical on both sides, it will not compile. In order to have identical property names in this sample, I added the `Date =` before my value.

By the way, you should use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) to test your queries, it is really a nice tool.

Comment: I didn't know ToList() Method fetchs all rows. And how can i prevent to fetch all rows!!? 1) Yes i "want to obtain the list of all writers (editors) along with the last article of each one of these writers" . 2) "Do you want to get the writers that did not write any articles yet also?" No but i want to learn how can i get both.

Comment: I waited very much. But it is very very very good explanation. Thank you very much...

Comment: Sorry for the wait but I was at work so I was testing this query in sapre time only (compilation, startup time of our application). Just to help me, I kept getting issues with my sample query. I am not comfortable yet when it comes to grouping in Linq...